# TOML loading config error with my pattern

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf, toml

I am trying to add stats from my dell server (IDRAC  6 EXPRESS) to grafana via telegraf and influxdb.
I using code from this dashboard and have this error:

```
2024-03-10T13:56:20Z I! Loading config: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
2024-03-10T13:56:20Z E! error loading config file /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf: error parsing data: line 22: invalid TOML syntax

Line 22:
pattern = "^(?P\d{4})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})\.(?P\d{6})(?P[-+]\d{3,4})$"
```

full code [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12106-idrac-host-stats/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying a TOML linter like: https://www.toml-lint.com/ to ensure your configuration is valid TOML first. To avoid escaping with normal quotes, consider using single quotes which indicate a string-literal in TOML:

```ini
pattern = '^(?P\d{4})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P\d{2})\.(?P\d{6})(?P[-+]\d{3,4})$'
```